# How to pop up dialog activity when app closed

Tags: android, service, android-runonuithread

I try to make sample application that show contact name and number from my local contacts when incoming call, every thing work correctly but my activity dialog didn't appear till call finished or terminated. I want to show this dialog like `TrueCaller` Application popup when call started or find any result, My dialog started correctly when found any result but i can't show it until call finished. I cant run it on UI Thread my logic in non activity class. Any help ?

following code show how i start my activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MyDialog.class);
intent.putExtra(MyDialog.NUMBER, number);
intent.putExtra(MyDialog.CONTACT, name);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

And i define my activity in `mainfaist` file

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.MyDialog"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/dialog_activity_style"/>
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out solution for this problem ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast `context` in your `Activity`.

like below code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MyDialog.class);
intent.putExtra(MyDialog.NUMBER, number);
intent.putExtra(MyDialog.CONTACT, name);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//change below line in your code
((Activity)ctx).startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I try it now but application stopped and dialog not shown `cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`

Comment: Yes you can not cast application context to Activity. You need to pass context of  current  activity.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement through intent service. When call is connected start service and display dialogue from service like:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
dialog.show();
```

and set permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```